# While creating node client getting org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using the below code to create a client node of elasticsearch. The same was working fine until now when suddenly I'm start getting MasterNotDiscoveredException. I have changed the config value as, but still the issue is same.

> discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

If I switch to TransportClient, the same is working. Please let me know what is the issue with node client

```
public static Client createESClient() {
    // creating a client node
    Node node =
        nodeBuilder().clusterName(CLUSTERNAME).client(true).data(false)
            .node();
    Client client = node.client();
    LOGGER.debug("the node has been created ");
    return client;
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$3.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:180)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I am stuck here too, so switched to using "TransportClient" which seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Consider adding tags, elasticsearch 2.0, java client. To increase discover.